# not getting the angularjs post data in controller (codeigniter)

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

I am making a HTTP request to a url, in which the data is getting post in request headers, but when I am fetching it in controller using the `$this->input->post`, it is showing blank.

**Angularjs code :**

```
//Code to send email of quiz results
$scope.processresult=function(){
    $http({
       method:"POST",
       url:"http://localhost/quizci/admin/sendresultemail/",
       data:{
           "riskscore":$scope.datascore
       },
   })
   .success(function (data) {

       if (!data.success) {
       // if not successful, bind errors to error variables
           $scope.errorName = data.errors.name;
           $scope.errorSuperhero = data.errors.superheroAlias;
       } 
       else {
           // if successful, bind success message to message
           $scope.message = data.message;
       }
   });
}
```

**Controller Function :**

```
 function sendresultemail(){
         $from_email = "test@test.com"; 
//         $to_email = $this->input->post('email'); 
         $to_email = "abc@gmail.com"; 

         $this->load->model('user_model');
         // $result = $this->user_model->get_user_by_id($this->session->userdata($sess_array['id']));
         echo "risk score =".$this->input->post('riskscore');
         exit;
         //Load email library 
         $this->load->library('email'); 

         $this->email->from($from_email, 'ERMS'); 
         $this->email->to($to_email);
         $this->email->subject('Email Test'); 
         $this->email->message($_POST); 

         //Send mail 
         if($this->email->send()){
           $this->session->set_flashdata("email_sent","Email sent successfully.");    
         } 
         else {
             $this->session->set_flashdata("email_sent","Error in sending Email."); 
             $this->load->view('admindash');

         }

    }
```

Refer below images, in [image: screen1]

you can see the data in request payload, but in the response it is showing blank [image: screen2]

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes codeigniter fails to get the post data. One solution that worked for me was to set $_POST manually using the following step:

```
 $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

then run the $this->input->post() function.

Hope that it helps some people.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention header content type.

```
$scope.processresult=function(){
                    $http({
                        method:"POST",
                       url:"http://localhost/quizci/admin/sendresultemail/",
                       headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                        data:{
                            "riskscore":$scope.datascore
                        },
                    })
```

In php.. ex..

```
public function store()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $posts = $this->input->post();
    $this->db->insert('posts', $posts);
}
```

Comment: i tried adding header earlier, but it gives "Disallowed Key Characters." error in CI , hence I removed that.

Comment: change headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, and php $obj=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

Answer (score 0):

You should return back json in CI not by echo its value.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $arr );
```

In addition, please don't use success in angular since it is deprecate, use then instead.

```
 $http({
        method:"POST",
        url:"http://localhost/quizci/admin/sendresultemail/",
        data:{
              "riskscore":$scope.datascore
         },
        })
       .then(function (resp) {
              var response = rest.data;
              // any code here
 });
```